# Deploy and run windows store app on remote device from command line

Tags: powershell, windows-store-apps, command-prompt

In Visual Studio you can go to properties->debugger, select remote debugging and enter the device's ip and port (with the remote debugging tools running on the remote device), hit deploy and press F5 (or ctrl+F5).

I would like to mimic that from a command line prompt or powershell. is there any way of doing that?

I saw lots of posts that suggest creating a package, signing it with a certificate, sideloading the app and running it on the remote device, but I would like to do that from the "master computer" without doing anything on the remote device. Has anyone found a way to do that? If not, how is automatic testing done on such apps?